# clr.dll causes 800703e9 on Microsoft .NET 4.6.1

Tags: .net, dll, clr

When using a DLL that works fine in a .NET-based Windows app in Excel 2013, it crashes the clr.dll:

```
Application: EXCEL.EXE
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an internal error in the .NET Runtime at IP 6F033A0F (6EDA0000) with exit code 800703e9.

Faulting application name: EXCEL.EXE, version: 15.0.4833.1000, time stamp: 0x573ac30d
Faulting module name: clr.dll, version: 4.6.1076.0, time stamp: 0x56d7a0ff
Exception code: 0x800703e9
Fault offset: 0x00293a0f
Faulting process id: 0x10d4
Faulting application start time: 0x01d1dceab78fdb9a
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office 15\root\office15\EXCEL.EXE
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Report Id: 1b887d31-48de-11e6-bbcc-005056c00008
```

The computer has VSTO 2010 installed on top of Windows 7 with all updates applied.

After upgrading to 4.6.2, the crash remained:

```
Application: EXCEL.EXE
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an internal error in the .NET Runtime at IP 57F3288A (57C80000) with exit code 800703e9.

Faulting application name: EXCEL.EXE, version: 15.0.4833.1000, time stamp: 0x573ac30d
Faulting module name: clr.dll, version: 4.6.1532.0, time stamp: 0x56e76357
Exception code: 0x800703e9
Fault offset: 0x002b288a
Faulting process id: 0x12c4
Faulting application start time: 0x01d1dcf3ff640774
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office 15\root\office15\EXCEL.EXE
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Report Id: 6b1fe8ad-48e7-11e6-ae61-005056c00008
```

On other devices running 4.5.2 the problem does not occur. It is either PC bound or .NET version bound.

Does anyone know what might trigger this internal error of clr.dll?

Comment: The last 4 hex digits is the Windows error code.  0x03e9 == 1001 == ERROR_STACK_OVERFLOW, "Recursion too deep; the stack overflowed".  Sure, the CLR reports it but did not cause it.  Always a programming bug, they named a web site after it.

Comment: which site do you mean :-?

Comment: @GuidoLeenders, I guess he refers to [this website](https://stackoverflow.com).

Answer (score 2):

Merits go to [Hans Passant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant). It was indeed a very nasty stack overflow occurring under some conditions.