# Windows Application Crash On Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: c#, windows, clr, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2

I have window application that crashes when i try to run it in 64-Bit Windows Server 2008-R2 Enterprise Edition. Then application uses .Net 4.6.1 which is already installed in server and developed in Visual Studio 2017. After i run the application the following errors appear in event viewer

> Application: MyApplication.exe
> Framework Version: v4.0.30319
> Description: The process was terminated due to an internal error in the .NET Runtime at IP 65B3191A (65880000) with exit code 800703e9.
>
> Faulting application name: MyApplication.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x5cffc5ed
> Faulting module name: clr.dll, version: 4.7.3416.0, time stamp: 0x5cabfd2c
> Exception code: 0x800703e9
> Fault offset: 0x002b191a
> Faulting process id: 0x93c
> Faulting application start time: 0x01d520f04b7a64c8
> Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)#####\MyApplication\Application\MyApplication.exe
> Faulting module path: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
> Report Id: 8f803530-8ce3-11e9-868d-005056856231

**NOTE:** The application works fine in windows 10,8.1,8,windows server 2012

I searched about the problem and found a solution which was installing a windows  hotfix, but i couldn't find it any where ( it is no longer available in Microsoft support )

Comment: I found something similar on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38349605/clr-dll-causes-800703e9-on-microsoft-net-4-6-1

Comment: Exception code 0x800703e9 is stack overflow exception (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/debug/system-error-codes--1000-1299-). Although the faulting module is clr.dll, the root cause is likely to be in your code. Try adding AppDomain.UnhandledException handler and log the exception to a file. The stack trace should shed some light on it.